# How to extract the css content from local css file and inject them into <style> tag?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I know that I can create my own style content into `<style>` tag using `style.innerHTML` like this

```
    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.setAttribute("id", "raptors");
    style.innerHTML =
      ".puma {" +
      "color: purple;" +
      "font-size: 50px;" +
      "text-align: left;" +
      "}";
```

However, instead of manually writing css into`style.innerHTML`, I would like to set the style content by importing styles from local file such as `./styles.css`. So something like this

```
styles.innerHTML = import `./styles.css`
```

So I came up with this `fetch` solution, but no luck. Is there a solution to this? https://codesandbox.io/s/stylesheet-fetch-experiment-ek4d1h?file=/src/App.js:267-646

```
    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.setAttribute("id", "test");
    async function loadCss() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("./style.css");
        const css = await response.text();
        style.textContent = css;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    loadCss();
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'no luck' - are you absolutely sure that your style file is in the right place? I am not clear what you mean by 'local file'. I assume it's on the server alongside your code file somewhere? Have you console.log the response to make sure you are getting the contents of the file?

Comment: Try this `style.innerHTML = css;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `style` element, you could create a `link` and set its `href`:

```
let link = document.createElement("link");
link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
link.setAttribute("href", "./styles.css");
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Slightly related: https://css-tricks.com/why-isnt-it-style-src/

Comment: Is there a way to unload the content of the link into `<style>` tag like this --> `style.appendChild(link)`?

Answer (score 0):

Import the stylesheet in you component, use the class name. That's it.

In `Component.tsx` or `Component.js`:

```
import "./Component.styles.css";

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div className="myDiv">
      something
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `Component.styles.css`:

```
.myDiv {
 color: red;
}
```